# HR gradient is not taking effect

Tags: css, border, gradient, linear-gradients

I can't tell my HR gradient is not taking effect or even displaying.

```css
hr.green {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px dashed;
    border-left: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    border-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(48, 183, 149, 1) 10%, rgba(130, 195, 65, 1) 100%) !important;
    border-image-slice: 1;

}


body {
background-color:black;

}
```

```html
<h1>
TEST
</h1>
<hr class="green">
```

Did I have a typo somewhere?

I was hoping to see something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the slice inside the `border-image` because it will also set the `border-image-width` which is missing here:

```css
hr.green {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px dashed;
  border-left: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(48, 183, 149, 1) 10%, rgba(130, 195, 65, 1) 100%) 1;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  TEST
</h1>
<hr class="green">
```

Comment: Am I removing this property `border-image-slice: 1;` ?  I saw you append `1` at the end. What is it ?

Comment: @code8888 it's the border-image-slice & the border-image-width. border-image is the shorthand version that accept all the values (like background)

Comment: Ok. Silly question, can I make them dim abit ? like adjust the opacity of the line ?

Comment: @code8888 by using the opacity property ?